# Can we use a predefined java function to be used in jpql queries?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

suppose i have the following code:

```
TypedQuery<Attendant> query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Attendant a WHERE FUNCTION('isAttendantAbsent', a.employeeId, a.attendanceDate) = true", Attendant.class);
List<Attendant> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

then i would like to register this function something like this:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit", properties);
HibernateEntityManagerFactory hibernateEntityManagerFactory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory;
SessionFactory sessionFactory = hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

((SessionImpl) session).getFactory().getFunctionRegistry().registerFunction("isAttendantAbsent", new IsAttendantAbsentFunction());
```

Is this kind of coding possible?
It would be even cooler if we could register it on the fly using spring repository classes

I haven't tried anything, just conceptualizing and trying to determine the possibilities.